# Python, Class and Inheritance testing

Tags: python-2.7

I've created two classes and I'm trying to test them but I'm getting the following error and cant for the life of me see whats wrong.

The idea is to use these classes as a module then grab input from the user to populate the arguments, but for now I'm just testing the classes.

**Error**

```
File "./Employees.py", line 38, in <module>
emp1Atr.displayAttributes()
AttributeError: Attribute instance has no attribute 'displayAttributes'
```

**Code below**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Employee:
    'Practice class'
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, salary):
            self.salary = salary
            Employee.empCount += 1
    def displayCount(self):
            print "Total Employees %d" % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
            print "Salary: ", self.salary


class Attribute(Employee):
    'Defines attributes for Employees'
    def __init__(self, Age, Name, Sex):

            def Age(self):
                    self.Age = Age

            def Name(self):
                    self.Name = Name

            def Sex(self):
                    self.Sex = Sex

            def displayAttributes(self):
                    print "Name: ", self.Name + "\nAge: ", self.Age + "\nSex: ", self.Sex


emp1Sal = Employee(2000)
emp1Atr = Attribute(12, "John", "man")

emp1Sal.displayEmployee()
emp1Atr.displayAttributes()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Employee:

'Practice class'
empCount = 0

def __init__(self, salary = None): #made salary as an optional argument
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1
def displayCount(self):
        print "Total Employees %d" % Employee.empCount

def displayEmployee(self):
        print "Salary: ", self.salary


class Attribute(Employee):
    'Defines attributes for Employees'
    def __init__(self, Age, Name, Sex):
        Employee.__init__(self) #Calling the parent class init method
        #Assigning Attribute the values passed in the __init__ method

        self.Age = Age
        self.Name = Name
        self.Sex = Sex  
#Making a class method which is why it is intended out of the init method
#This was the reason you got the first error of display attributes
def displayAttributes(self):
print "Name: ", self.Name + "\nAge: ", self.Age , "\nSex: ", self.Sex #Changed the + to ',' between self.Age and "\nSex"


emp1Sal = Employee(2000)
emp1Atr = Attribute(12, "John", "man")

emp1Sal.displayEmployee()
emp1Atr.displayAttributes()
```

Comment: I dont see the difference sorry

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you please explain what you did, ive only been learning a few days so im a nub :(

Comment: O right, i wasnt aware you had to call the parent as I thought it was inherited? Im confused :(

Comment: Its always a good idea to call the parent init if you have manually overridden it

Answer (score 0):

If that is a proper copy paste, then your indentation in the Attribute class is one too deep. All methods after the `__init__(self)` are indented as if they where local methods inside of `__init__(self)` instead of the object. So if you outdent them properly and set the attributes `age, name and sex` in `__init__()` properly, it should work.

Comment: I did think it was to far indented but I get an error if i dont indent it

Comment: File "./Employees.py", line 21
    def Age(self):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just retried it with out the call to the parent and it works. Could you please explain why you added that line?

**New Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Employee:
    'Practice class'
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, salary):
            self.salary = salary
            Employee.empCount += 1
    def displayCount(self):
            print "Total Employees %d" % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
            print "Salary: ", self.salary


class Att(Employee):
    'Defines attributes for Employees'
    def __init__(self, Age, Name, Sex):
            self.Age = Age
            self.Name = Name
            self.Sex = Sex

    def display(self):
            print "Name: ", self.Name + "\nAge: ", self.Age,  "\nSex: ", self.Sex


emp1Atr = Att(12, "Da", "man")


emp1Atr.display()
```

Comment: Ok so when defining the __init__ arguments It must be in the same instance, it cant be in a different def? That makes sense doh!

Comment: Well its not required but just a good practice so, that you can propagate the arguments to the parents.